# how can I define plan and executing it in Kiss FFT

Tags: fft, kissfft

do you see any mistake in the following?

```
cfg = kiss_fftr_alloc(dim,1,NULL,NULL);
kiss_fftr(cfg,in,out);
```

is it equal to: ?

cfg = fftw_plan_dft_c2r_1d(dim, in , out, FFTW_ESTIMATE);
fftw_execute(cfg);

Answer (score 0):

Looks pretty close, except the default type for kiss_fft_scalar is 'float', whereas the fftw_* functions are based on 'double'.